# Need 2 functions to run onLoad with Ajax - only 1 working

Tags: javascript, ajax, onload

Starts with shuffle functions (just shuffles arrays). It works.
Then I define 2 global variables that will determine the random order for images to be displayed on the page.
picOrder will be a simple array from 0 to picCount, with picCount determined by Ajax onload. The picCount is being retrieved, but the the picOrder array is not being set! If I manually run "arrangePics();" in the console it works. It fills the array picOrder and then shuffles it. But it does not work by placing the calls to both functions inside "" or by putting the "doStuff()" function in there.

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
var s = [];
while (this.length) s.push(this.splice(Math.random() * this.length, 1)[0]);
while (s.length) this.push(s.pop());
return this;
}

var picOrder = new Array();
var picCount;

function getPicCount() {
//  picCount = array(10);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            picCount = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/example.com/images.php?count=hello",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    //picCount.shuffle;

}

function arrangePics() {
    for(var i = 0;i<picCount;i++) {
    picOrder[i] = i;
    }
    picOrder.shuffle();
    //alert(picOrder);
}
```

HTML

```
<body onLoad="getPicCount();arrangePics();">
```

or

```
<body onLoad="doStuff();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `arrangePics()` *after* the asynchronous AJAX call has returned, i.e. you can only call it in the `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {}` (callback) block otherwise you cannot be sure that the data has been fully received.

What is currently happening is that JavaScript is calling `getPicCount();arrangePics();` - the first method initiates the AJAX call and returns immediately and then the second method will by trying to arrange 0 pics. Executing `arrangePics()` manually on the console would have introduced enough delay into the system for the AJAX call to complete and the `picCount` would be set as expected.

So if you change the callback function to:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    picCount = xmlhttp.responseText;

    for(var i = 0;i<picCount;i++) {
        picOrder[i] = i;
    }
    picOrder.shuffle();
}
```

it should shuffle the pics after the count has been received.